# Why do I keep getting an "expected expression" error in VSC?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn **modules** in python. I created a *greeting message* but it keeps giving me an `expression eror` even though it doesn't seem to have `your text` any mistakes.

```
    from nabercanokolpacino import nabero
    from bye import oldcustomer
    print("are you new here?(answer yes or no)")
    x=input(">>")
    if x=="yes":{
        global o 
        o = input("name:");
        nabero(o)
    }
    elif x=="no":{
       oldcustomer()
    }
```

As you can see in the code above, this should be printing some stuff inside a function from `nabercanokolpacino` and `bye`. If I said yes or no but its not working because of the `expession error`.

Comment: A lot of things are wrong in your code. I suggest you follow some tutorial on python to understand the language's syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly brackets.

```py
from nabercanokolpacino import nabero
from bye import oldcustomer

print("Are you new here? (answer yes or no)")
answer = input(">> ")
if answer == "yes":
    name = input("name:")
    nabero(name)

elif answer == "no":
   oldcustomer()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code, hover the mouse over the red line to see the error message.

[image]

Simple modified code:

```
from nabercanokolpacino import nabero
from bye import oldcustomer
print("are you new here?(answer yes or no)")
x=input(">>")
if x=="yes":
    global o 
    o = input("name:")
    nabero(o)

elif x=="no":
   oldcustomer()
```

Also make sure to use a python interpreter with `nabercanokolpacino` and `bye` installed.

You need to install the extension [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*

Comment: And you don't need `global` here.  `global` is totally useless outside of functions.

Comment: Sorry, the main purpose of my answer is to remind the OP to use the extension to view the error and modify it, so I only modified the code so that no red warning appears. Apologies again for the otherwise unreasonable code.

Comment: No, I was not critiquing your answer, I was just trying to add an additional reminder for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of syntax mistakes in your code. Your need to remove the curly braces. Modified code:

```
#Import modules
from nabercanokolpacino import nabero
from bye import oldcustomer

#Get user input
print("Are you new here?(answer yes or no)")
x = input(">>")

#Check user input
if x == "yes":
    global o 
    o = input("name:");
    nabero(o)

elif x == "no":
   oldcustomer()
```

Now you need to make sure that you have installed the nabercanokolpacino and oldcustomer modules to your Python interpreter.